# DataAnnotation [Key] makes a field readonly, is there other?

Tags: data-annotations, silverlight-5.0

The Key DataAnnotation makes a field behave as ReadOnly when I use it in a DataForm or DataGrid since it denotes a DataBase key, but what if I just want to make it readonly because it's a calculated field?

**Is there another DataAnnotation, other than Key, to make a field behave as ReadOnly in a DataForm?**

[image: Window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the  [Editable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.editableattribute.aspx) annotation, with AllowEdit as false.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Editable(AllowEdit = false)]
```

Comment: How could I set the "Account Number" label to plain text instead of bold. It doesn't have the [Required] atribute, though it's still bold??